# How to add a clip path to image in tailwind

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am looking to make a clip path to do dividers on my website. I want to clip out my solid white background and allow the image in the section below to go up into it.

I have seen css examples, but I am using Tailwinds and Next.jS

I cant seem to find any help on this.

normally in CSS you can do this.

```
header {
  clip-path: polygon(
    0 0,
    100% 0,
    100% 100%,
    0 calc(100% - 6vw)
  );
}
```

but using tailwind and React, I dont see how to do this.

I am trying to get an effect like this.

[This is what Im trying to achieve with React/NExt.js and tailwind](https://codepen.io/erikdkennedy/pen/KaZLwe)

Comment: Kindly provide some code ref.

Comment: Provided more detail.

Comment: There are no clip-path utilities in Tailwind. You'll have to write custom CSS to handle this.

Comment: @brc-dd provided an awesome link. upvoting him.

Comment: @brc-dd this was perfect! It does what I want it to do with a solid background. What if my section below is an image and I want it to fill up that slant with the image instead of the white area?

Answer (score 19):

in React, go to your **index.css** file, where **@tailwind** directives are present & at there create your **own custom utility class** under *utilities directive*, as like -

```
@layer utilities {

   .clip-your-needful-style {

       clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 calc(100% - 6vw));

   }

}
```

then you can **call** your **custome class** into your JSX inside className="**clip-your-needful-style**"

Hope it will work in your case...

Answer (score 6):

You may go crazy and use some tailwind magic and without a need to create your own class in css. Smth like this

```
<div class="[clip-path:polygon(0%_0%,100%_0%,100%_100%)]">
  ...
</div>
```

Although not sure if it will work with `calc` and syntax is a bit ugly. 
Resource: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-properties

Answer (score 0):

Here's my [idea](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/6061) on implementing clip-path into Tailwind CSS, which covers the slant-down designed sections you want.

To skew element by 3 degrees (approx.) you could apply CSS like: `clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 2.25rem, 100% 100%, 0 calc(100% - 2.25rem))`

In the Tailwind world, let's use utility classes instead:

```
<section class="bg-gray-300 h-72 clip polygon b-3 d-3">
  <div class="container"></div>
</section>
```

Then in the global Tailwind CSS file use the clip-path utility (polygon shape in this case) and its values (e.g. dimensions a-3, b-3, c-3, d-3 as below)

```
@layer utilities {
  * {   --tw-clip-polygon: var(--tw-clip-polygon-a), var(--tw-clip-polygon-b), var(--tw-clip-polygon-c), var(--tw-clip-polygon-d);
  --tw-clip-polygon-a: 0 0;
  --tw-clip-polygon-b: 100% 0;
  --tw-clip-polygon-c: 100% 100%;
  --tw-clip-polygon-d: 0 100%;
  }

  .clip.polygon.a-3 {
    --tw-clip-polygon-a: 0 2.25rem;
  }

  .clip.polygon.b-3 {
    --tw-clip-polygon-b: 100% 2.25rem;
  }

  .clip.polygon.c-3 {
    --tw-clip-polygon-c: 100% calc(100% - 2.25rem);
  }

  .clip.polygon.d-3 {
    --tw-clip-polygon-d: 0 calc(100% - 2.25rem);
  }

  .clip.polygon {
    clip-path: polygon(var(--tw-clip-polygon));
  }
}
```

There's already [plugin](https://github.com/mellambias/tailwind-clip-path) for precise dimensions, that you could use instead.

It would be amazing, though, if someone can rethink my idea with other shapes like ellipses, and circles... along with the dimensions for the most used use cases.